# just show last result in FOR loop of Joomla module

Tags: php, arrays, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

This is my code in tmpl/defult.php of my Joomla 2.5 module:

```
$result = count($payed);
for($i=0;$i<$result;$i++)
{
   $pay=F.$payed[$i];
   echo "<td>".JText::_("$pay")."</td>";
   echo "<td>".number_format($item->$pay)."</td>";
   $paytotal=$pay+$paytotal;  // For last result
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

`$payed` is an `Array`. I get it from user and exploding by this Code :

```
$p = $params->get('pay_fields');
$payed = explode ("\n", $p);
```

in language file of this module I used general names for module parameters, like these :

```
F1="pay1"
F2="Pay2"
F5="Pay3"
F6="Pay4"
```

and my table in Database has column name like this:

```
F1  |  F2  |  F3  |  F4  |  F5  |  F6  |  F....
---------------------------------------------------
12  | 1247 | 1056 | 2368 | 2256 | 12510| ...
```

I want to make a table from all user entered database fileds.
For example when user types in module parameters

```
1
2
5
6
```

script must be read F1,F2,F5 and F6 from Database and make table . 
I know script do this , but not exactly true !
it just shows last result ! and set 0 for other parameters!
what's wrong ?

Know Module shows this result in frontend :

```
--------------------------------
F1     |          0
--------------------------------
F2     |          0
--------------------------------
F5     |          0
--------------------------------
Pay4   |       12,510
```

Comment: This doesn't explain your problem, but you should use `'F' . ` not `F .` - you want the string `'F'`, not the value of the constant `F`. For backwards compatibility, PHP guesses what you mean, but it's bad practice to rely on it.

Comment: I tried this but the answer did not change.

Comment: could you give me a clue. what is F?

Comment: F is a Prifix of My Dtabase Table Column.F1 name of Fisrt Column , F2 Second Column , F3 Third Column ,...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved with a funny way!

**I just Change seperator From `" \n "` to `" ; "` and enterd number with the new symbol !**

But I still do not understand what the problem was!

However, now it is working fine :D.